# how to avoid gaps on the distribution of hair on a model?

Tags: particles

How do I get particle hair on a model I made, with out it resulting in many spots on the mesh with no hair at all?

Here is a picture of the problem.

[image]

Often the gaps are on the tail arms and legs.

[image]

Comment: Use interpolated Children and augment particle numbers if needed bro.

Comment: Hair particles are able to cover all the faces of a mesh. Maybe some your  setting are not pointing in this direction (ex. it's emitting from verts instead of faces, it has a density texture...). Could you post a 1/2 screenshot of them and add more information?

Comment: i posted the problem now.

Comment: Please use the "edit" button below your question, instead of posing additional information as  "answers."

Comment: Maybe some faces are facing the wrong direction. Have you tried to recalculate normals (Edit Mode > Ctrl + N)?

Answer (score 3):

### Particles with Interpolated Children

Probably in some parts of your mesh, the particles (hair in this case) are not dense enough.

Interpolate option creates children based on the "main" particles properties (location, orientation...)

[image]

if these particles (main) are not enough, increasing the number of children would not help in filling the gaps. Notice how the spiral patter is similar to the one in your screenshots.

The image was made by adding a Particle system (Hair type) and tweaking the following values:

- **Emission Number** = 100
- **Interpolated Display** = 280

By disabling the Interplated children option, you can see the particles that actually are generated. These are the only one that will be truly affected by simulations, hair editing...the children will simply follow their properties.

[image]

---

You must ensure that the "main" particles are well distributed upon the mesh, and only at that point you can increase the overall density with childrens.

[image]

The image was made by adding a Particle system (Hair type) and tweaking the following values:

- **Emission Number** = 4000
- **Interpolated Display** = 7

Notice how the thinner part of the mesh is full of "guiding" particles.

Result:

[image]

Comment: Could you add an explanation of how to get from the second to the third image?

Comment: @PGmath He have activated the "Interpolated" option. See the difference in "Children" panel of both images.